# Does Thinkpad E430 Hard Drive Fit into Dell Vostro 1310?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I'm going to have my Thinkpad E430 repaired. So I want to place its hard drive into an older laptop - a Dell Vostro 1310.

How can I know whether this hard drive fits into the older laptop or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know whether this hard drive fits into the older laptop?

Regular modern (as in, build in the last decade) laptops allmost all use the same format 2½ inch SATA drive. This means is it almost guaranteed that the drive will physically fit into another laptop.

Some caveeats:

1. I wrote 'physically fit'. This does not mean that you can boot the OS which is already on it. Generally this is not a problem when you use Linux or BSD, but windows is rather tied to the hardware which it was installed on. You might be able to work around that by using sysprep. But you will have to do that twice. (Once in a working Thinkpad E430 before you move it to the older laptop. Once before you move it back). Windows may also ask for re-activation.
2. Netbooks and Ultrabook might use smaller drives (e.g. 1.8inch or drives).
3. Huge (for their time) laptop drives sometimes are taller than average (> 9.5mm). (This would be mentioned in the laptops manual).

For practical reasons (and assuming that the Thinkpad is already broken): Just put the drive in an external eSATA or external USB caddy. Access the data from there and keep the drive as it is until your Thinkpad is repaired.